# Ubuntu: move logs from /dev/tty8 to different terminal /dev/tty12 or get rid of it

Tags: ubuntu, logging, terminal, console

I want to know how to move or get rid of `/dev/tty8` log output in Ubuntu 9.10. `/dev/tty7` is my regular X session. When I am switching user to test account where I can try and test setups and configs I am at next available console i.e. `/dev/tty9` because `/dev/tty8` is taken by  log output. Where can I configure this ? All I've found related to `/dev/tty8` is commented  lines in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. I changed it like that:

```
daemon,mail.*;\
 news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
 *.=debug;*.=info;\
 *.=notice;*.=warn /dev/tty12
```

And I've got nice log output on `/dev/tty12` but where is configuration for log output on `/dev/tty8`. How can I change it?

**EDIT 1:**

with `grep -R '/dev/tty8' /etc/*` I found some clearing commands on VT 8 in `/etc/init/usplash.conf`:

```
/etc/init/usplash.conf: tput -Tlinux reset > /dev/tty8 || true
/etc/init/usplash.conf:    clear >/dev/tty8 || true
```

Clearing and reseting ... hmmm. But where is config responsible for redirecting log output and from what ?

**EDIT 2:**
`lsof | grep tty` gives no output for `/dev/tty8`. So no process is writing to it, right? `/dev/tty1-6` are associated with `getty` and `/dev/tty7` is associated with `Xorg`, nothing for `/dev/tty8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is `usplash`. I've found that after decompressing initramfs and looking around. `tty8` output console is hard-coded into the source. So solution is:
1. download sources for usplash package
2. modify sources for every `tty8` you find.
3. modify sources for ifs checking if `fgconsole` is 8 and similar for instance `chvt` command
4. rebuild package & install it.
5. reboot.

Now what was on `/dev/tty8` is on your virtual terminal of choice. In my case `/dev/tty11`. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the change you made, try this:

```
$ sudo setlogcons 12
```

You could add `setlogcons 12` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: It does not work. I've tried it in `/etc/rc.local`. Also `setlogcons(8)` says that log level can be set with `dmesg`. I've tried that too with `dmesg -n`. No output on virtual terminal.